# React js and PropTypes repetition across shared components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've created some react components and as such, the parent... gets a few props...

Every subsequent child then uses most of these props, then children of children.

```
**--> Parent**
(required props)
**-------> child**
(required props)
**-------> child**
(required props)
**------------> sub child**
(required props)
**------------> sub child**
```

those "required props" are the same for all those components. Seems excessive that whenever I update a prop in Parent, I then have to go into all those children and update to (if they are required). Of course, they are required and needed, but curious if there is a shortcut/or implementation that this repeating is not necessary. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the question.  What do you mean update the property?  you mean change the property name? like physically change the name in the javascript file?

If you're talking about having props value update from parent to child, well that is what state is for, it should update any child props based on that parent state value.

Comment: Is {...this.props} what you looking for maybe? Passing all props to the next component.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can store your prop types in an object that you merge into the each component's `propTypes`:

```
var requiredPropTypes = {
    foo: ...,
    bar: ...
};

var ComponentA = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        ...requiredPropTypes,
        // ComponentA's prop types follow
        // ...
    },
    // ...
});

var ComponentB = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        ...requiredPropTypes,
        // ComponentB's prop types follow
        // ...
    },
    // ...
});
```

---

The value of `propTypes` is just an object. How you build that object is completely up to you.

Comment: hmm. that seems doable. but I don't want to have to make that value global... else, how else would I be able to get it into every child? Thanks for your response, btw, appreciate it.

Comment: How you organize your code is up to you. There is no need to make the shared types global, the just have to be accessible where they are needed. If you are working with modules, make the shared props a module and import it where needed.

Answer (score 6):

This is pretty simple. If your writing es6 code, you can use the shape of a component that you import

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';    
import { Button } from 'components';

const NewComponent = (props) => {
    return (
        {props.buttons.map((button) =>
            <div>
                <Button {...props} />
            </div>
        )}
    );
}

NewComponent.propTypes = {
    buttons: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({ Button }.propTypes))
};
```

Comment: Using propTypes from another component is not safe because they may be removed in production builds.

Answer (score 1):

The [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) might be handy:

```
import OtherComponent from './OtherComponent';

const MyComponent = ({ foo }) => (<OtherComponent {...foo} />);

MyComponent.propTypes = {
    foo: PropTypes.shape({ ...OtherComponent.propTypes }),
};

export default MyComponent;
```